# Dynamic application of several polynomials

Tags: map

I know how to get the 'resulting image' (y) from the application of a certain function (f) (here represented as the coefficients of a polynomial) over a certain interval (x):

```
x = Range[27000]/27001.;

f = {25.62, -38.43, 21.81}/9;

y = Map[f[[1]]*#^3 + f[[2]]*#^2 + f[[3]]*# &, x];

ListPlot[y]
```

How do i get the 'resulting images' from the application of several polynomials (represented as its coefficients) over a certain interval (x)?

Considering the representation of those several polynomials to be something like:

```
polynomials = Map[
{9 + #[[1]] - #[[2]], -#[[1]], #[[2]]} &,
Flatten[Outer[
            List,
            {23.75, 28.02, 32.29, 36.56, 40.83, 45.1, 49.37, 53.64, 57.91, 62.18},
            {13.48, 15.9, 18.33, 20.75, 23.17, 25.6, 28.02, 30.44, 32.87, 35.29}
            ],
        1]
]/9;
```

Comment: Guys, thank you guys very much for your solutions. In other forum I've received one suggestion, and I would like your opinion, since I'm far away from Mathematica for about 10 years. Considering process cost and ease of understanding, which you think is the best? Among each of yours and his, which is:

y[f_] := (f.#^{3, 2, 1} &) /@ x;

ListLinePlot[Evaluate[y /@ polynomials], Frame -> True, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500]

Comment: @belisarius? :o)

(my comment/question above)

Comment: @bill-s? :o)

(my comment/question above)

Comment: @michael-e2? :o)

(my comment/question above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar approach is to define a function

```
 Clear[x]; p[x_, {a_, b_, c_}] := (a x^3 + b x^2 + c x)/9;
```

and then build a table of polynomials. Using the variable `polynomials` from the OPs question, these could be plotted as

```
 Plot[Table[p[x, polynomials[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[polynomials]}], {x, 0, 1}]
```

This leads to substantially the same plot as belisarius, but there are a few differences. This uses `Plot` instead of `ListPlot` because it's plotting the polynomials instead of the sampled values of the polynomials. As a consequence, the polynomials are being plotted against the values of `x` rather than against the index of a list of `x` values.

Comment: your solution is really flexible and general... thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I understand the question. Anyway.

To get all the images, just:

```
y1[f_] := Map[f[[1]]*#^3 + f[[2]]*#^2 + f[[3]]*# &, x];

ListPlot[y1 /@ polynomials]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

Another possible nterpretation of your question is that you are trying to apply the polynomials sequentially, but there is a divergence near the end of the list getting notorious starting around the poly nbr. 26:

```
x = Range[300]/301.;
y1[f_][x_] := f[[1]]*#^3 + f[[2]]*#^2 + f[[3]]*# &@x;
ListLinePlot[Fold[y1[#2] /@ #1 &, x, polynomials[[1 ;; 25]]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
 ListLinePlot[Fold[y1[#2] /@ #1 &, x, polynomials[[1 ;; 26]]], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: your answer was really direct and practical... and I meant the first understanding you had... thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

In reply to your comment above, if you want to get the values (images) of all your `polynomials` at a large number of values of `x`, then something like this will be fastest:

```
y = polynomials.(x^# & /@ {3, 2, 1})
```

If you want to only plot the polynomials, then use `Plot`, not `ListPlot`, and the formulas for the polynomials.  Each of the three current answers has way (@bill s, @belisarius, and mine).  I think you would be the best judge of which has the greatest ease of understanding.  I don't think to get the formulas, process speed matters much until you have lots of polynomials.

**Original**

Here's function that takes a list of coefficients (*edit* now assuming no constant term) and returns a polynomial function:

```
polyFn[coeff_List] := Function[{x}, Evaluate@Fold[x (#2 + #1) &, 0, coeff]]
```

Example:

```
polyFn[{a, b, c}][x]
(* x (c + x (b + a x)) *)
```

The function `polyFn[{a, b, c}]` can be evaluated at many points in one call and it will take advantage of the built-in vectorized functions `Plus` and `Times` automatically:

```
polyFn[{a, b, c}][{1, 2, 3}] // Expand
(* {a + b + c, 8 a + 4 b + 2 c, 27 a + 9 b + 3 c} *)
```

Ten random coefficents for ten polynomials:

```
polys = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}];
polynomials = polyFn /@ polys

(* {Function[{x$}, x$ (0.682011 + (0.64716 + 0.179604 x$) x$)],
Function[{x$}, x$ (0.327702 + (0.417207 + 0.832486 x$) x$)], 
    ... omitted ...
Function[{x$}, x$ (0.684578 + (0.196256 + 0.159777 x$) x$)]} *)
```

And evaluate them all on the same set of inputs:

```
images = Through[polynomials[Range[0., 2, 0.1]]];
```

`Through` takes each function in the list `polynomials` and applies to `Range[..]`.
Voilà:

```
ListLinePlot[images]
```

[image: Plot of ten polynomials]

---

I am accustomed to polynomials being represented with the coefficients in the other order, from constant to higher degree, so that the index in the list corresponds to the degree of the term (off by one if one starts with a constant term).  The correspondence can be convenient, but then one has to change `polyFn`:

```
polyFn[coeff_List] := Function[{x}, Evaluate@Fold[#2 + x #1 &, 0, Reverse@coeff]]
```

Both versions handle arbitrarily long lists of coefficients (i.e., arbitarily high degree polynomials).

And of course you can use `Plot` with them, as @bill suggests.  Use

```
Plot[Evaluate[Through[polynomials[x]]], {x, 0, 2}]
```

Comment: your answer was really complete... thank you very much!