# Matrices and polynomials: MMA 8 vs. 9?

Tags: programming, matrix, version-9, version-8

I want a function to take a polynomial from a list, plug a certain matrix *T* into that polynomial, and return the answer as another matrix. My program uses the *applyPoly* function suggested by a user in response to:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17394035/in-mathematica-how-calculate-pa-where-p-is-a-polynomial-and-a-is-a-square-mat

Here is my code:

```
applyPoly[poly_, var_, A_?MatrixQ] := 
  With[{c = CoefficientList[poly, var]}, 
    c.MapIndexed[MatrixPower[A, #2[[1]] - 1] &, c]]

Compute[a_, b_, c_] := (
  p[x_] := x^4 - c*x^3 - b*x^2 - a*x; 
  T := {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, a}, {0, 1, 0, b}, {0, 0, 1, c}}; 
  L := FactorList[p[x]]; s = Length[L]; R = {}; 
  Do[R = Append[R, Simplify[p[x]/L[[i + 1, 1]]]], {i, s - 1}]; 
  u = Length[R]; 
  Do[r[x_] := R[[i]]; Print[applyPoly[r[x], x, T]], {i, u}])

Compute[1,2,3]
```

In Mathematica 8, this returns the correct matrix output:

```
{{-1,0,0,0},{-2,0,0,0},{-3,0,0,0},{1,0,0,0}}

{{0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,2},{0,0,1,3}}
```

But in Mathematica 9, I get an error:

> Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered. >>
>
> {-1,-2,-3,1}.{MatrixPower[{{0,0,0,0}, {1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,2},{0,0,1,3}},0],{{0,0,0,0},       {1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,2},{0,0,1,3}}, {{0,0,0,0}, {0,0,1,3},{1,0,2,7}, {0,1,3,11}}, {{0,0,0,0},   {0,1,3,11}, {0,2,7,25}, {1,3,11,40}}}
>
> Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered. >>
>
> {0,1}.{MatrixPower[{{0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,2},{0,0,1,3}},0],{{0,0,0,0},{1,0,0,1},{0,1,0,2},{0,0,1,3}}}

I understand that 8 and 9 must handle matrix or list objects in different ways. What is the difference, and how can I alter my program so that it works in 9?

Comment: I think `MatrixPower` chokes on your matrix not being positive-definite...

Comment: It's funny, because the documentation says that `MatrixPower` was last modified in version 6.

Comment: In version 9, have you tried `MatrixFunction` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks I did try `MatrixFunction` but I seem to remember it had problems with using list entries. I'll get back to you later when I can look at those files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Print` for output; change `Do` to `Table`.  Then the output will be the matrices (with the `Root` objects), and `N` will work.

```
applyPoly[poly_, var_, A_?MatrixQ] :=  MatrixFunction[poly /. var -> # &, A]

Compute[a_, b_, c_] := (p[x_] := x^4 - c*x^3 - b*x^2 - a*x;
  T := {{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, a}, {0, 1, 0, b}, {0, 0, 1, c}};
  L := FactorList[p[x]]; s = Length[L]; R = {};
  Do[R = Append[R, Simplify[p[x]/L[[i + 1, 1]]]], {i, s - 1}];
  u = Length[R];
  Table[(*r[x_] := R[[i]];*) applyPoly[(*r[x]*)R[[i]], x, T], {i, u}])
```

*Edit:* I commented out the (unnecessary) definition of `r`, thanks to [sebhofer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/368), and replaced it with `R[[i]]`.

---

Example

```
Compute[1, 2, 3] // N

(* {{ {-1. + 0. I, 0., 0., 0.},
      {-2. + 0. I, 2.53644*10^-16 + 0. I, 3.20011*10^-16 + 0. I, 1.68815*10^-15 + 0. I},
      {-3. - 4.93038*10^-32 I, 7.28119*10^-16 + 0. I, 8.93665*10^-16 + 0. I, 3.69631*10^-15 + 0. I},
      {1. + 0. I, 3.20011*10^-16 + 0. I, 1.68815*10^-15 + 0. I, 5.95812*10^-15 + 0. I}},
    { {0., 0., 0., 0.},
      {1. + 0. I, 0. + 0. I, 0. + 1.38778*10^-17 I, 1. + 0. I},
      {-3.40006*10^-16 + 0. I, 1. + 5.55112*10^-17 I, 0. + 0. I, 2. + 2.77556*10^-17 I},
      {-4.996*10^-16 + 0. I, 2.77556*10^-17 + 0. I, 1. + 0. I, 3. + 0. I}}} *)
```

---

There are other ways ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10067/convert-an-expression-to-a-function), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13757/how-to-make-a-function-that-evaluates-an-expression), [3](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21340/dynamic-application-of-several-polynomials)) to turn a polynomial `poly` into a function, but the above was the easiest, given your setup.

---

The above was rather too long to put into a comment, but I think [bill s](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1783) deserves the credit for pointing out `MatrixFunction`.

Comment: I agree, this seems like an adequate solution. I don't have enough rep to vote up bill s but I appreciate his help.

Comment: Note that the `r[x_] := R[[i]]` doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @nardol5 I just want to point out that `MatrixFunction` shows the same behaviour as `MatrixPower` if asked to compute `T^0` (where `T` is not positive definite), which caused your code to fail in the first place! Try `MatrixFunction[#^0 &,T]`.

Comment: @sebhofer Quite right.  I didn't look at the code closely enough.  One can simply have `applyPoly[R[[i]], x, T]` in the `Table`.

Answer (score 2):

[`MatrixFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MatrixFunction.html) is the way to go... for example:

```
MatrixFunction[#^5 + 2 #^2 + 1 &, {{a, 1}, {0, b}}]
```

gives the polynomial function `x^5+2x^2+1` when x is the symbolic matrix `{{a, 1}, {0, b}}`. It also works for more complicated functions such as trigonometric functions. And of course, it works on numerical matrices as well. It does require that the matrices be square, which makes sense because otherwise the x^n terms don't make any sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I replace `applyPoly[r[x], x, T]` with `MatrixFunction[r[x],T]` in the code above, it returns:

Comment: `MatrixFunction::nunipf: -1-2 x-3 x^2+x^3 is not a univariate pure function.` I suspect that MatrixFunction has issues with list elements, but I don't see how I can avoid using a list in my program. @bill s

Comment: @nardol5 The error message says it all... Try MatrixFunction[Function[x, R[[1]]], T]

Comment: @sebhofer Your suggestion works for individual cases, but in my program it produces a long list of expressions similar to: `Root[-1-2#1-3#1^2+#1^3 &, 1]^2`. I'm not really sure what's going on (being new to programming in MMA) but I might be able to make Function work for me somehow.

Comment: That's the symbolic form. Put `N[ ]` around it to see a numerical version.

Comment: @bills Applying `N[]` does not change the expression.

Comment: @nardol5 I'm not quite sure what you are doing then because it gives me `13.1578`

Comment: @bills The output I'm getting includes several hundred Root expressions, with several polynomials in x thrown in for good measure. I tried placing `N[ ]` in my program inside the Print command, in several different ways. It did not lead to any understandable output either.

Comment: Why not build up your answer from the pieces you have, rather than trying to solve a single large problem all at once?

Comment: @bills I guess that's what I need to do. This is actually part of a larger program I was writing for a research project. I was just trying to make my code as compact as possible.

Comment: Also, I think my institution is upgrading their MMA license to 9 in a few days, so I won't be able to take advantage of the difference in 8 anymore.